# get only date from the text file

Tags: linux

get only the date from the multiple log files with the date format.

ex:log file 1

```
Info    10/24/2013  6:42:18 PM  Core    1   Initializing appilcation Novicorp WinToFlash 0.7.0048 beta
Info    10/24/2013  6:42:18 PM  Core    2   Started from D:\system use\os\Win To Flash 0.7.0048 Beta\WinToFlash.exe
Info    10/24/2013  6:42:18 PM  Core    3   Loading options
Info    10/24/2013  6:42:18 PM  Options 0   Options loaded
Warning 10/24/2013  6:42:19 PM  License 0   License file doesn't exists - EULA status reset
Error   10/24/2013  6:42:30 PM  Network 0   The server does not respond
Error   10/24/2013  6:42:49 PM  Network 0   The server does not respond
Error   10/24/2013  6:42:49 PM  Network 0   The server does not respond
Info    10/24/2013  6:45:02 PM  Core    9   Application termainated
```

ex: log file 2

```
09/22/2014 08:10:24.363 [1876]: Uninstalling assembly System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
09/22/2014 08:10:24.363 [1876]: Executing command from offline queue: install "System"
09/22/2014 08:10:24.379 [1876]: Uninstalling assembly PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0
09/22/2014 08:10:24.379 [1876]: Executing command from offline queue: install
```

in the above example the two examples are given the different columns but i want only get the date

my coding:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file_name in /media/saraswathy/7284EA0684E9CD23/Log/data/input_files/*.log;
do
while read file_line
do
echo $file_line | date +%Y:%m:%d -d "1 day ago"

done<$file_name
done
```

pls help me

Answer (score 2):

`grep` would help you. Assuming the date are in this format: `mm/dd/yyyy`, then you could use:
`grep '[0-9]\{2\}/[0-9]\{2\}/[0-9]\{4\}' -o`

#### Explanations:

- `[0-9]`: to parse a digit.
- `\{2\}`: to repeat for 2 times. `\` for escaping the brackets.
- `-o`: to print only the part that parses (instead of printing the whole line)

#### Example:

```
[pengyu@GLaDOS tmp]$ grep '[0-9]\{2\}/[0-9]\{2\}/[0-9]\{4\}' -o a.log
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done with awk tool - e.g. you are able to print whatever column you want with many other options (separator, regex etc.). Simply place the column number (indexed from 1) after $ sign.

```
$ awk '{print $2}' example1.log
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013
10/24/2013

$ awk '{print $1}' example2.log
09/22/2014
09/22/2014
09/22/2014
09/22/2014
```

The same effect also can be done with e.g. cat or tile and pipe:

```
$ cat example1.log | awk '{print $2}'
$ tail example2.log | awk '{print $1}'
```